# Modifying Array Length property through Reflection

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, reflection, private

So, I am stuck with one weird problem.

To give you idea what I want to achieve, but failed miserably:

```
int[] testArray = new int[100];

typeof(int[])
.GetProperty("Length", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
.SetValue(testArray, 50);
```

Yeah, that is, I want to modify C# arrays Length property (only make it less than actual size), **without** making new array and copying contents - to avoid GC etc etc...

Background:

In Unity, there is this function:

```
void SetIndices(int[] indices, MeshTopology topology, int submesh, bool calculateBounds);
```

As you see, `SetIndices` doesn't accept "start" and "end" or at least "length" as a parameter. This is why I want to modify Length of my indices array to trick this function.

Any ideas?

Comment: The Length property is read only. Setting it won't do anything afaik.

Comment: I realized that, is there any private member I can modify?

Answer (score 1):

You can't resize an `array` in C#. That's the hard truth.

In fact, the `Array.Resize` method creates a new array and copies the values of the previous array in the new one.

Comment: I don't want to resize it, infact I want to keep array itself intact. I just want to modify Length property.

Comment: What would be the point of modifying **only** the `Length` property without modifying the actual length of the array? That's a recipe for disaster and on top of that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why recipe for disaster? I just want to make Length less or equal than real array length.

And reason why, because the API I want to use reads that Length property & because I dont want to allocate new array everytime (which can be big as ~200kb) when I call this function. 

Trust me, it isn't without sense.